I am replacing head gaskets in a VY Commodore do you have to disconnect timing chains
I have  a VY Holden Commodore that I am changing head gaskets in I was wondering  do you need to disconnect timing chains to take the heads off ?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Since this is an overhead valve (OHV) design, you shouldn't need to remove the timing chains to take the heads off. This applies to either the V6 (L36 NA or L67 Supercharged) or the V8 (LS1).
